# Как сделать временной цикл while внутри которое for

Tags: python

как сделать так, что бы цикл while в котором цикл for работал по времени которое укажет пользователь

Comment: Советую изучить библиотеку time и (если та не поможет) datetime.
Всё функции данных библиотек помогут с решением задач связанных со временем. Всю информацию можно найти в интернете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не уверен, что правильно понял вопрос, но, например.

Если надо, что бы цикл for отрабатывал до конца, вне зависимости от превышения временного лимита, то:

```
import time
a = 0
time_limit = 5
start = time.time()
while time.time() - start <= time_limit:
    for i in range(100):
        a += i ** 2
    print(f'\r{a}', end='')
```

Если же надо, чтобы оба цикла прерывались, то добавим break по вкусу:

```
for i in range(100):
    if time.time() - start > time_limit:
        break
    a += i ** 2
    # или сюда break с условием
```